# Calulating coefficiencies

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to calculate the number ofcoefficiencies of every $x^k$ 
in the expansion of $(x-\frac{1}{x})^{100}$ for an arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Now I tried the following formula: 
$\binom{100}{k}$ eventhough similar to the demonstration, 
Something is missing here (and/or the lack of explanation makes it harder to understand). 
help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{100}=x^{100}\left(1+(-x^{-2})\right)^{100}.$$ Now try the binomial theorem on the right-hand side.